# String comparison seems not to work

Tags: javascript, string, string-comparison

I have strings that I have to insert in a db but I want to first modify their value if they fall under certain conditions.

For example I have the strings `Epatite`, `Epatite B`, `EpatiteáB`, `EpB3` that I want them to be changed to `EP B` before being inserted into the db.

This is piece of my code:

```
// vaccines[index] is the string to compare
var vac = makeUniform(vaccines[index]);
const queryInsert = {
    text: 'INSERT INTO coverages (vaccine) VALUES ($1) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;',
    values: [vac]
}
var printText = '[INSERT Italy IN coverages]';
promises.push(postgreSQLlib.query(queryInsert, printText, false));

function makeUniform(val) {
    if(val === 'DIF' || val === 'Difterite') {
        return 'DIPH'; // diphtheria
    }
    else if(val === 'Epatite' || val === 'Epatite B' || val === 'EpatiteáB' || val === 'EpB3') {
        return 'EP B'; // hepatitis B
    }
    else if(val === 'HIB' || val === 'Hib3' || val === 'Hib') {
        return 'HIB'; // haemophilus influenzae B
    }
    else {
        return val;
    }
}
```

Whene I execute `SELECT DISTINCT vaccine FROM coverages ORDER BY vaccine;` on psql shell, I get:

```
DIPH
DT-DTP3
DTP3
EP A
EP B
EpatiteáB
Hib
HIB
M-MPR1
M-MPR1-MPRV ...
```

There is `EpatiteáB` which theoretically should have changed in `EP B`.
Why it doesn't work?

---

## EDIT 1

`vaccines[index]` comes from an online pdf of which I did web scraping using the [`textract` package](https://www.google.it/search?ei=fDPDWsSVBqTX6AS9j7jYCw&q=textract%20npm&oq=textract%20npm&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i203k1.4015.6281.0.7026.9.6.2.1.1.0.215.704.3j2j1.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.6.389...0j0i19k1j0i13i30i19k1j0i13k1j0i13i10k1.0.q2sB-n9Yi_A) of Node.js.

Thanks

Comment: A character encoding issue?

Comment: @Teemu Is it possible, how can I solve it?

Comment: That depends on where `vaccines[index]` is coming from ..?

Comment: Just to certify the possibility of encoding issues, I would add some logging just before the check (i.e. as the first statement of the `makeUniform` function).

Comment: Try to match using the substring 'Epatite' instead.

Comment: Check this post to see how to match the substring. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript

Comment: You do an insert, not an update, so it doesn't get changed.

Comment: @giubueno I solved using val.includes('Epatite'). Thanks!

Comment: You may want to try calling `normalize()` on `val` before comparing. `'á'` may be encoded as `'\u00E1'` or `'\u0061\u0301'`. Try this: `'á' === 'á'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your development database first with this:

```
UPDATE coverages set vaccine = 'EP B' WHERE vaccine LIKE 'Epatite%' OR vaccine = 'EpB3';
```

Do something similar for the others.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this added one more condition = (val==="Epatite%E1B%21")

```
function makeUniform(val) {
    if(val === 'DIF' || val === 'Difterite') {
        return 'DIPH'; // diphtheria
    }
    else if(val === 'Epatite' || val === 'Epatite B' || val==="Epatite%E1B%21" || val === 'EpatiteáB' || val === 'EpB3') {
        return 'EP B'; // hepatitis B
    }
    else if(val === 'HIB' || val === 'Hib3' || val === 'Hib') {
        return 'HIB'; // haemophilus influenzae B
    }
    else {
        return val;
    }
}
```